# empty html-tags in xls ouput / multiple if's

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a XML with customer details (Company name, adress, zipcode, city, honorific, firstname etc.etc.)

```
   <Addresses locale="AU">
  <Address>
    <Honorific/>
    <FirstName/>
    <LastName/>
    <CompanyName>Braschs Pty Ltd</CompanyName>
    <CompanyName2/>
    <Address1>71 Sheridan Street</Address1>
    <Address2/>
    <PostalCode>4870</PostalCode>
    <City>Cairns</City>
    <City2/>
    <District/>
    <StateCode>QLD</StateCode>
    <State>Queensland</State>
    <CountryCode/>
    <Country/>
  </Address>
</Addresses>
```

And a xsl file which should give me the output in the order the address in Australia is written. (Different countries have different ways to write an address)

```
<xsl:template match="//Address[../@locale='AU']">
    <address>
    <p>
        <xsl:if test=" Honorific != '' "><xsl:value-of select="Honorific" />&#160;</xsl:if><xsl:if test=" FirstName != '' "><xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />&#160;</xsl:if><xsl:if test=" LastName != '' "><xsl:value-of select="LastName" /></xsl:if>
    </p>
        <h4><xsl:value-of select="CompanyName" /></h4>
        <p>
            <xsl:if test=" CompanyName2 != '' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="CompanyName2" /><br />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address1" /><br />
            <xsl:if test=" Address2 != '' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="Address2" /><br />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="City" />,&#160;<xsl:value-of select="StateCode" />&#160;<xsl:value-of select="PostalCode" /><br />
            <xsl:if test="Country!= '' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="Country"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </p>
    </address>
</xsl:template>
```

Which gives me that output:

```
<address>
<p />
<h4>Braschs Pty Ltd</h4>
<p>71 Sheridan Street<br />Cairns, QLD 4870<br />
</p>
</address>
```

I have one empty p-tag now because none of the values inside the p-tag are available(honorific, firstname, lastname).

So what would be my best option to get rid of the empty tags? Can I check my output for empty tags and remove them?

I thought about an if-direction like:

```
<xsl:if test=" Honorific != '' " or "FirstName != '' ">
```

But I get an error that " is at the wrong spot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one empty p-tag now because none of the values inside the p-tag
>   are available(honorific, firstname, lastname).
>
> So what would be my best option to get rid of the empty tags? Can i
>   check my output for empty tags and remove them?

Yes, you could do this along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="Address[../@locale='AU']">
    <address>
        <xsl:if test="string(Honorific) or string(FirstName) or string(LastName)">
            <p>
                <!-- handle Honorific, FirstName and LastName here -->
            </p>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- the rest of the code here -->
    </address>
</xsl:template>
```

And a more elegant way to "handle Honorific, FirstName and LastName" would be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Honorific[string()] | FirstName[string()] | LastName[string()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or do the same thing by applying templates to them.